# Log Spring-boot request body using ContentCachingRequestWrapper

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to log request body by  implementing  HandlerInterceptor using [ContentCachingRequestWrapper](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/ContentCachingRequestWrapper.html), and i'm following this [article](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-http-logging) and [git](https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/tree/master/spring-boot-modules/spring-boot-runtime/src/main/java/com/baeldung/web/log/app) repo but was unable to read the data from the request. Below is the code snippet.

I am following the above approach to log the request body for only the post request any help would be appreciated.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.google.common.io.ByteSource;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.slf4j.MDC;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerInterceptor;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping;
import org.springframework.web.util.ContentCachingRequestWrapper;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;

@Configuration
public class MyHandlerInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyHandlerInterceptor.class);

    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Autowired
    public MyHandlerInterceptor(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        this.objectMapper = objectMapper;
    }


   @Override
   public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {

    ContentCachingRequestWrapper wrappedRequest = new ContentCachingRequestWrapper(request);
    wrappedRequest.getParameterMap();
    Map<String, Object> pathParams = (Map<String, Object>) wrappedRequest
            .getAttribute(HandlerMapping.URI_TEMPLATE_VARIABLES_ATTRIBUTE);

    Map<String, Object> treeMapOfParam = new TreeMap<>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
    treeMapOfParam.putAll(pathParams);

    if (HttpMethod.POST.toString().equals(wrappedRequest.getMethod())) {
        
         String payloadData = null;
        ContentCachingRequestWrapper contentCachingRequestWrapper = WebUtils.getNativeRequest(wrappedRequest, ContentCachingRequestWrapper.class);
        if (null != contentCachingRequestWrapper) {
            byte[] buf = contentCachingRequestWrapper.getContentAsByteArray();
            if (buf.length > 0) {
                payloadData = new String(buf, 0, buf.length, contentCachingRequestWrapper.getCharacterEncoding());
            }
        }

        logger.info(payloadData);    //After the above block payloadData is still null

    } else if (HttpMethod.GET.toString().equals(wrappedRequest.getMethod())) {

        logger.info("helloget");

    }
    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: That won't work. You need a filter for that.

Comment: Can you show an example and I am looking if there is any chance using interceptor.

Comment: There is no change in using an interceptor. You need a filter to wrap the request/response and pass it downstream. You cannot do that with an interceptor.